# Putting a variable on the canvas with other text

Tags: python, variables, text, tkinter

I am trying to get a variable from a user's input, and then put that variable onto the canvas, saying (if they choose '250') 'Whoever gets to 250 first wins!'.

```
def GameLengthTwoPlayer():
    canvas.delete(ALL)
    global tk

    def print_it(event):
        global name
        name = var.get()
        TwoPlayer()

    var = IntVar()
    var.set("Choose the Score Limit")
    optmen = OptionMenu(tk, var, 20,50,100,250,500,1000, command=print_it)
    optmen.configure(width = 20)
    optmen_window = canvas.create_window(350,400, window=optmen)
```

This gets the user's input with a drop down box. However, the is a problem when I try and put the variable 'name' into a canvas.create_text, it doesn't work.

```
global name
obj= name
str(obj)
canvas.create_text(350, 355,  fill='red', font =('Bauhaus 98',20), text='Testing' + obj + 'test')
canvas.pack() #Packs canva
```

I get 'TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly' as an error, but haven't I just turned it into a str?

If anyone could help fix this, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You turned it into a string but you didn't save it anywhere

`global name
obj= str(name)
canvas.create_text(350, 355,  fill='red', font =('Bauhaus 98',20), text='Testing' + obj + 'test')
canvas.pack() #Packs canva`

Comment: you can also just convert it into str within the `create_text`, if you don't need the variable `obj` enywhere else. Like: `canvas.create_text(350, 355,  fill='red', font =('Bauhaus 98',20), text='Testing' + str(name) + 'test')`